# How to fix 'Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver' error in Flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I got this error in android build when I try ro run: flutter run

D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/rauleburro/Develop/Bellbird/aseguradora_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

BUILD FAILED in 7s